# How to autofill an HTML form field using and external .txt with PHP

Tags: php, forms, autocomplete, fulfillment, txt2tags

The main question is: I have a .txt with all the airports in the world, and like every airport, there is a coordinate containing an latitude, and longitude data, like this:

ICAO  Latitude  Longitude

SAWH-54.843334 -68.295556

SAWE-53.777500 -67.750000

SCDW-53.610700 -70.470525

SCFM-53.253611 -70.319167

The ICAO code, is a code that every single airport has. Is it possible to make a form that when I type de ICAO code, Latitude, Longitude gets self fulfilled, reading this .txt on my virtual server?

Comment: It is all interesting. But, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is there anyway to get this list as a CSV? It would be 100x easier as PHP has built in functions for rendering CSVs.

Comment: I am totaly LOST! I don't know how to begin! My form is done, but i would like to add this feature. I can get this list as a CSV, but the ICAO code, lat, and lon, will stay in the same line.. there is any problem? I will search a little bit!

Comment: That is similar to what i want: http://openflights.org/html/apsearch    and here is an "easier to work" database that i found it: http://openflights.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/openflights/openflights/data/airports.dat